# Sending block chunks through TCP

Tags: multiplayer, minecraft-modding, data

I am creating a 'Minecraft clone' and the game is going to be only multiplayer. I currently have a limited world (it's not going to be infinite) that is *512* chunks.

Each chunk is *16(X)* * *16(Z)* * *128(Y)* of blocks.

Each block is represented by a byte. This means I have a 3D array of bytes that represents which block is in which position in the chunk (*0 means Air*). I got to the part where I want to send the world though the TCP connection.

I am using *KryoNet* for my multiplayer needs. Currently what I do is I flatten the 3D array to the highest Y coordinate that is not air, making my (16 * 16 * 128) array into a (16 * 16 * *less than 128*) array. After doing this I take the 3D array and flatten it into a 1D array. After doing that I have a 1D array of size *~32,000*. Obviously sending the entire *32KB* of data through the connection at once is stupid and it also crashes *KryoNet*.

My question is how would I efficiently go about sending *512* chunks (512*32 KB of data) through the connection?

I thought about separating the 1D array (*32,000* bytes) into 32 packets each of 1KB of data but it seems odd to send 512 * 32 packets to send the world (*~16,000* packets).
Is there any way to compress this data or send it in a more efficient way through my TCP connection? Obviously this is done once per session but still *16,000* seems a lot.

**Progress update:**

I have separated the chunks into 33 packets each, and I send them one after the other. It seems to be working well, but I have a slight ordering issue that is unrelated. At the times that it works it loads quite quickly and with no problem! If there is a more efficient way of going about this please do post it here!

Comment: Why do you think it would crash KryoNet? When you download a file with a web browser, you can transfer gigabytes of data via TCP/IP.

Comment: Yeah but not at once. It does crash Kryo. It cannot serialise so much data at once.

Answer (score 1):

Besides splitting up the data in multiple packets as you've already proposed, you could try 2 more things:

The first (and simplest) is to do run [length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) on the data.

Run length encoding is when, instead of saying "Stone,Stone,Stone,Air,Air,Air" you say "3,Stone,3,Air". In typical minecraft style maps that saves a *lot* of data and it is used in most games like it.

Besides run length encoding, if you're dealing with this much data, and data for which latency isn't *that* big a deal, try using a generic compression algorithm!

Java already has an implementation for GZIP, try sending the data to a memory buffer via a [GZIPOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) and sending that data, it should be a lot smaller.
(Speed wise, this is something that can rather easily be done in another thread so it shouldn't affect the game much)